# 75w Ampeg tube amp with 16 ohm output jacks

Tags: amplifiers, speakers

I have 2 15" Altec 421A 8 ohm speaker cabinets but would like to also use an 18" EV speaker also.

The Ampeg amp has 2 16 ohm speaker output jacks.

How would I hook them up or should I use the 2 8ohm cabinets only?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t use any of that unless it’s connected correctly. Can you add a picture of any labels or words printed on the Altec speaker cabinets? Also which exact model Ampeg is it? The danger is that using both Altecs might actually present a 4 Ohm load, not 16, and that would be quite dangerous for the Ampeg.

Comment: In your position, I'd go straight to Ampeg, tell them all the impedances and get a schematic from them. Straight from the horse's mouth..?